# In Flutter Quill，how can i get the input value like TextField onChange

Tags: flutter, textfield, quill

I want to get the input value when input is changed,just like TextField onChange. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `_controller.document.toDelta()` to extract the deltas.

Use `_controller.document.toPlainText()` to extract plain text.

Answer (score 1):

We can use controller for getting the changes.

_controller.document.changes.listen((event) {

});